# Java stream approach to partition elements based on sum of the object property

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, greedy

Given a List of objects with an integer property, I want to partition the list into multiple lists, grouping the elements by summing them based on a property until a maximum threshold is reached. Is there a supported way to do this with the Java Stream APIs, rather than maintaining the sums/counts in a for loop?

Example desired function:

```
class Foo {
    String id;
    int price;

    public Foo(String id, int price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Foo("one", 1));
        list.add(new Foo("two",1));
        list.add(new Foo("three",1));
        list.add(new Foo("four", 1));
        list.add(new Foo("five",2));
        list.add(new Foo("six",3));

        int maxPrice = 3;
        // Expected output: [[{"one", 1"}, {"two", 1}, {"three", 1}], [{"four", 1}, {"five", 2}], [{"six", 3}]]
        List<List<Foo>> partitioned = partition(list, maxPrice);
    }

    private static List<List<Foo>> partition(List<Foo> list, int maxPrice) {
        return list.stream()
                .????
                .collect(???)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the maximum represents and how it's applied?

Comment: I want to sum each element by the "price" property until the sum of the elements in the partition hit the maximum, and at that point start a new partition.

Comment: Seems like a very stateful operation, which is not what streams are designed for. If it's possible, it won't be pretty or efficient.

Comment: I would try to approach this by creating a custom collector, and it would probably be less clear than for-loops. Why do you want to use a stream? Is it because you have `filter()` or `map()` operations that you want to apply in your pipeline before the `collect()` terminal? Or is it because you are under the (sorely mistaken) impression that loops are "bad" or "outdated"?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments definitely looks like not the best idea to use streams in this case. However if you really need to, you can use this hardly readable snippet below ;)

```
private static List<List<Foo>> partition(List<Foo> list, int maxPrice) {
    List<List<Foo>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Foo> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

    list.forEach(element -> {
        if (tempList.stream()
                .reduce(0,
                        (sum, m) -> {
                            return sum += m.price;
                        },
                        Integer::sum)
                + element.price <= maxPrice) {
            tempList.add(element);
        } else {
            resultList.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
            tempList.clear();
            tempList.add(element);
        }
    });
    resultList.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really using streams. The OP wants to `stream()` the input `list`. You are just incidentally using a stream to accumulate the prices, and one can do that more expressively with `tempList.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.price).sum()`

Comment: Yes, I know but it was closest I could get :) You think its possible at all to do streaming the input?